# Alternative to deprecated FileSystemEntry.remove() function?

Tags: javascript, html5-filesystem, native-file-system-api-js

I am using the new(ish) [File System Access API](https://web.dev/file-system-access/) and I need to delete a file. I was going to use the [remove() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemEntry/remove), but it is deprecated. Is there a currently supported function for deleting files in the File System Access API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should try this:

https://wicg.github.io/file-system-access/#api-filesystemdirectoryhandle-removeentry

The removeEntry() method